# Call function or method inside mainpage flutter

Tags: flutter

I make mainscreen with bottomnavifationbar with 3 pages, how can i call function inside mainpage from inside 1st page ? Or how can i use onactivityresult/resume (like in android native) ?

Comment: You should try a state management technique

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to answer since we don't know the structure of your code. I will assume you have 4 state*Widget (stateful or stateless), one for the root page (with it is the navigation bar) and three more for the single pages.

This tip is useful also if the structure it's not exactly the way I'm assuming it is.

You can write the function you need in the root page, passing that as a variable in the new page constructor (using the type **Function** or **VoidCallback**) and then you call it whenever you want.

Generalizing: you can always write a function and call it somewhere else passing that function through widgets with their constructor as **Function** or **VoidCallback**.